# How to copy a specific row to a specific row in one sheet? (Google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a script that takes a certain row and copies it to a certain row.

I have already found many solutions for this. The problem is that these solutions always look at the last row of a whole sheet. I only want the last row from column. Can anyone help me? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I was just writing an answer but I am not clear on what you need exactly. Can you show a simulation of what a 'before' and 'after' running the script would look like?

Answer (score 0):

script :

```
function daily_transfer_stockcars() {
  var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                                     //GDoc
  var sourcess = sp.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1");                                 //Source_Sheet
  var source_range = sourcess.getRange("J5:N5");                                      //Source_Data_Range
  var targetss = sp.getSheetByName("Tabellenblatt1"); 
  source_range.copyTo(targetss.getRange("J" + (getLastDataRow(targetss,"J")+1)), {contentsOnly: true});
}
function getLastDataRow(sheet,col) {
// col en letter
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(col + lastRow);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }              
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick answer! Where should i add your function?

Comment: in the script editor, after the last `}` ... pls post a spreadsheet if necessary

Comment: ok, im asking because i get an error message: TypeError: target_data_range.getRange is not a function

Comment: I didn't fix your script, but indeed you may need to change target_data_range to targetss, please post a spreadsheet if needed and a complete script

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cVprI-H3bsM6nrGhoOGa34z3bv764vYWV7lOOJgXz8k/edit#gid=0

Comment: do you need additional help (access to your spreadsheet is denied) ?

Comment: If you could help me, that would be great, otherwise I won't get anywhere. I could give you access if you ask for it.

Comment: test it ! let me know if you need something else